# Convert column value from null to value of similar row with similar values

Tags: powerquery

sorry for the slightly strange Title I couldn't think of a succinct way to describe my problem.

I have a set of data that is created by one person, the data is structured as follows

**ClientID ShortName WarehouseZone RevenueStream Name Budget Period**

This data is manually inputted, but as there are many Clients and Many RevenueStreams only lines where budget != 0 have been included.

This needs to connect to another data set to generate revenue and there are times when revenue exists, but no budget exists.

For this reason I have gathered all customers and cross joined them to all codes and then appended these values into the main query, however as warehousezone is mnaually inputted there are a lot of entries where WarehouseZone is null.

This will always be the same for every instance of the customer.

Now after my convuluted explanation there's my question, how can I

```
-Psuedo Code that I hope makes sense. 
SET WarehouseZone = WarehouseZone WHERE ClientID = ClientID AND 
WarehouseZone != NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that a client has one WarehouseZone? otherwise you need a aggregation.
Let's check, you can add a custom column that will return a record like this:

```
Table.Max(
    Table.SelectColumns(
        Table.SelectRows(#"Last Step" , 
            each [ClientID] = _[ClientID]) 
        , "Warehousezone") 
    ,"Warehousezone" 
)
```

This may create a new column that will bring the max warehousezone of a clientid everytime. At the end you can expand the record to get the value.

P/D The calculation is not so good for performance

Comment: I did manage to get a working solution that was a lot more complicated than this one involving creating multiple queries- merging and other fun methods. If I get a chance I'll confirm if this solution works as it would be a lot easier to manage than my Frankenstein monster!